# Unable to change inline css with jinja

Tags: python, html, css, flask, jinja2

I had to change the background image of the jumbotron below based on the input taken from the database.
Here's the code:

**housekeeping.html**

```
<div class="jumbotron" style="background-image:url('{%block wallpaper%}{%endblock%}');padding-left:5%;width:100%;background-size: 100%; background-repeat: no-repeat;">
```

**profile.html**

```
{%extends 'housekeeping.html'%}
...
...
{%block wallpaper%}{{wallpaper}}{%endblock%}
```

**app.py**

```
@app.route('/name/<b64>')
def profile_for_song(b64):
    ... 
    ... #retrives the value of `wallpaper` form a row in the database.
    ...
    wallpaper = '/static/wallpaper.jpg' #dummy value. 
    return render_template('profile.html', wallpaper=wallpaper)
```

but it doesn't work, as the value of `background-image:url('')` remains null.

Is it not possible to alter css with jinja blocks?

PS: I tried with `url_for` but still nothing.

Comment: @Selcuk sorry that was a typo when I was formatting here on stack overflow, I've fixed it now

Answer (score 2):

Watch the use of [whitespace](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#whitespace-control) control in your wallpaper block in profile.html.

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    wallpaper = '/static/wallpaper.jpg'
    return render_template('profile.html', wallpaper=wallpaper)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

**housekeeping.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="jumbotron" style="background-image:url('{% block wallpaper%}{% endblock %}');padding-left:5%;width:100%;background-size: 100%; background-repeat: no-repeat;">
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**profile.html**

```
{%extends 'housekeeping.html'%}

{% block wallpaper -%}
    {{ wallpaper }}
{%- endblock %}
```

**Sample output**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="jumbotron" style="background-image:url('/static/wallpaper.jpg');padding-left:5%;width:100%;background-size: 100%; background-repeat: no-repeat;">
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```